# FPDF encoding on writing not working in Python

Tags: python, fpdf

I'm trying to create a PDF file using Python and FPDF. I've read the project's page about unicode and I've tryed to follow their instructions, but everytime I run my program, I receave the error:

> File "eventsmanager.py", line 8 SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character
>   '\xc3' in file eventsmanager.py on line 8, but no encoding declared;
>   see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details

This is my program:

```
from fpdf import FPDF

pdf = FPDF()
pdf.add_page()

pdf.add_font('gargi', '', 'gargi.ttf', uni=True) 
pdf.set_font('gargi', '', 14)
pdf.write(8, 'Olá!!')
pdf.ln(20)

pdf.output('tuto3.pdf', 'F')
```

Can you help me understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you clarify: a) version of python, b) encoding of your(or not) file eventmanager.py ?

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7. and I've just noticed I forgot to declare the encoding in the first line!! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to declare that the file encoding is UTF8 as Python 2 defaults to Latin-1. UTF8 became default in Python 3. The linked PEP contain the required line that you have to add at the beginning of the file:

```
# coding: utf8
```

This must be the first line after the `#!` line

EMACS and VIM formats are also supported.

It is sad that the error message doesn't include the solution.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I forgot the encoding, I'm new to Python and that's something I'm always fogetting!!

Answer (score -2):

If you are using Python 3.x you have to use:

```
pdf.output(dest='S').encode('latin-1','ignore')
```

or

```
text=text.encode('latin-1', 'ignore').decode('latin-1')
```

in order to get the output.